# From where is leaflet loading data after hot module reload?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using `react-leaflet`, and after webpack triggers a hot reload, GeoJSON features remain on the map, but none are present if we check `map._layers` on load, like this:

```js
map.whenReady(() => console.log(map._layers))
```

Similarly, using `map.eachLayer` doesn't work, since leaflet apparently doesn't yet know about the layers.

But if I open the Chrome console and check `map._layers` manually, the layers are present. Why is this delay happening, and how can I wait for them to load so I can clear them?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [React-Leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#mapcontainer), you can see that the `whenReady` method doesn't take in the map instance. The `whenCreated` method, however, does:

[image: React-Leaflet Documentation for MapContainer]

If you want to access the map instance once the map has been rendered, you should be using the `whenCreated` map method rather than the `whenReady` method.

You can also use the `whenCreated` method to set the map to state and access it in a `useEffect` hook, for eaxmple. Here is an example component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    if (map) {
      console.log(map.eachLayer((layer) => console.log('USE EFFECT:', layer)));
    }
  }, [map]);

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', padding: 0 }}
        whenCreated={(map) => {
          console.log('MAP:', map);
          console.log(map.eachLayer((layer) => console.log('LAYER:', layer)));
          setMap(map);
        }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

Here is a demo on StackBlitz you can play around with: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntup5n?file=src/MapComponent.jsx)

---

If you want to access the map instance from the `useMap` or any other hook, you just have to make sure that you are using the hook [in a descendant of a MapContainer](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';

const ChildOfMapContainer = (props) => {
  // Set up the useMap hook in the descendant of MapContainer
  const map = useMap();

  // Access the map instance:
  useEffect(() => {
    // map.eachLayer((layer) => console.log('Layer:', layer));
    map.whenReady(() => map.eachLayer((layer) => console.log(layer)));
  }, [props, map]);

  return (
    <>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={props.position}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </>
  );
};


const MapComponent = () => {
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];
  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', padding: 0 }}
      >
        <ChildOfMapContainer position={position} />
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

[Sandbox with this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hjt2id?file=src/MapComponent.jsx)

Comment: My map instance is the return value from `useMap`, which typescript says doesn't have a `whenCreated` method. Is there a way to do this on the `useMap` instance instead?

Comment: Sure, just make sure that you are using the hook inside of a descendant of `MapContainer`. I've updated my answer to include a new example for this. I hope it helps!

Comment: The second example is using `whenReady` instead of `whenCreated`. This method isn't working for me. If we log the layers from inside of the `whenReady` callback, it's empty.

Comment: To be able to assist further, I would need to see more code. Consider adding more details/code to your question. Hard to tell what's going on from a single line of code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask